# CSS Gradients - negative border radius

Tags: html, css

I'm implementing a design, which has the following 'flourish' in the bottom right of a box:

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD3lt.png)

I'm wondering if there's a nice way to do this with CSS only. My easy, but not ideal, solution is to have an inner and outer div. The outer div has the yellow background colour, whilst the inner div has the teal colour.

The inner div has a bottom border radius, with two values specified to give me the ellipse.

Ideally I'd like to be able to do this without the wrapper element, but I've had no luck so far. I feel it must be possible, using either gradients or some such, but haven't managed to crack it yet!
I've also looked at http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/beveled-corners-negative-border-radius-with-css3-gradients/ but that's not quite right and results in a jagged edge..

Any tips?

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
}

.inner {
  background-color: teal;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 70% 80px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

EDIT: Code and Codepen example with the double divs: https://codepen.io/sebbornidentity/pen/xdqpxG

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: Sorry - updated the question with the code I had

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Instead of trying to put the orange element on top, put it on the bottom, where the teal element can have the border radius instead (and the orange one shows through). Simple example:

```css
#thing {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: teal;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

#thing:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: orange;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="thing"></div>
```

[`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) is used here to put the orange element behind the teal element.

Comment: Thanks - that is what I had tried but it wasn't working for me.

Comment: Turns out - I had another element (an image) positioned absolute adjacent to the container. Apologies, I didn't give that full context. Giving the container `position: relative;` fixed it and it's now working nicely with a pseudo element - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a pseudo element and get a cleaner markup.

The 50% control the bottom (horizontal) length and the 70% the right (vertical) length.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  background: orange;
}
div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: teal;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 70%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

The nice with a pseudo, it can have both borders and shadows

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
}
div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: teal;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 70%;
  border-bottom: 4px solid orange;
  border-right: 4px solid orange;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #999
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This is the exact same solution I used.

Comment: @LoganDark Are you saying I copied yours? ... Also do note, we both answered within a minute, which makes it perfectly fine if they would been the _exact_ same, though they are quite different if you take a closer look.

Comment: No, I'm not saying you copied mine.

Comment: @LoganDark Great, may I then ask why state they are the same, when they are not? ... I am simply curious why you wrote that comment in the first place

Comment: I don't even know why I posted that comment to be honest.

Comment: @LoganDark That is perfectly fine ... now I know :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example using `.inner` and `.outer` divs. You can use a `/` to manipulate the vertical and horizontal values of the `border-radius` property. If you want to learn more, check out this [link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/).

```css
html, body {height: 100%;}

.outer {
  height: 100%;
  background: #F5C154;
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 0 400px 0 / 0 0 100px 0;
  background:  #82C4B7;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

You can also use a `radial-gradient` to get the job done. But, this solution requires a pseudo-element. Also, note that this example doesn't give you much room to manipulate the `border-radius`. This is because radial gradients are perfect circles. Here's the working example:

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 220px -190px, teal 400px, orange 0);
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks although that's the solution I had (having said that I hadn't posted my code up so fair enough!)

Comment: Oh, sorry about that! I'll make an example of a radial-gradient solution.